# SOSTOOLS - Express a Matrix polynomials as Polynomial

Tags: matlab, sum-of-squares-method

We know that to express an polynomial as SOS, we can write it as a [Matrix SOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_SOS#Matrix_SOS)

Now we take an example, use [SOStools](https://www.cds.caltech.edu/sostools/) in Matlab to get SOS for
$$f(a,b,c)=16(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3-9\left[(a^3+3b^2c)^2+(3ac^2+b^3)^2+(3a^2b+c^3)^2\right]$$
Use the following command

---

$\text{syms a b c}\\
\text{option.solver = 'sedumi';}\\
\text{p=16*(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3-9*(a^3+3*b^2*c)^2-9*(3*a*c^2+b^3)^2-9*(3*a^2*b+c^3)^2;}\\
\text{[Q,Z]=findsos(p,'rational',option);}$

---

Then we can found a Matrix SOS.

Now I want to express this Matrix SOS as SOS polynomials (I mean the sum of SOS), how can I do it in Matlab or Maple?

I have read the user's guide, and I found a piece of related information:

[image]

But I still don't know how to use this for my problem. Thanks for help!